# Weird problem with Images Components

Tags: image, delphi

My problem is when I open my old project (project that work by same Delphi Version), I lost the entire image picture contents. By this I mean picture property is None.

When I open dfm with notepad, the picture property has Data but when I open it with delphi, its picture data will disapear. It seems that Delphi recognize picture data invalid.
(in this situation Delphi erase all data).

This happen with all Image Components and all Components that have Picture Property

I encounted this problem when I reinstall Delphi, and I am now running Delphi version 2007.

Comment: Well I can't explain why this happened. But I can tell you what to do about it. Do not ever store binary blobs of data in .dfm files. Put them in resources instead. That way you keep control and visibility of your binary assets. You'll have them in your version control system.

Comment: i will never use this approach but i must fix this problem, because my program have 300 image component that almost all pictures disapeare

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is probably caused by a missing package supporting the stored image format. Check for any image or graphics library that has been installed on your previous system and is missing in the current one. A good candidate for that is always [GraphicEx](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=13&Itemid=33).

Comment: I'd guess it's the PNG images that are giving you grief. Does 2007 have built-in PNGImage unit?

Comment: Exactly,This Problem arise From a miss package, But I don't know what package make this problem(I Install GraphicEx But Don't Fix - seems it is more a runtime package). i know my pictures format was jpeg and png, and already my delphi can read both format and no problem With new Projects, is it possible that a package change picture format when save them in dfm !? Also Some Picture in my old projects is Ok. please offer more packages that might make this problem.

Comment: Mr David, are you mean, is my image Component open PNG? Yes, it's open PNG and Jpeg, i have old original Pictures(png files) and i open thos with image component without any problem

Comment: @user you could try posting one of your dfm files to a pastebin and seeing if anyone can work out what's in it

Comment: PNG is natively supported since D2009, but there are different PNG supporting packages for older versions available. The DFMs are probably made with a different one.

Comment: One of the commonly used PNG support components before integrated support in Delphi 2009 was this http://www.torry.net/quicksearchd.php?String=png+delphi&Title=Yes

Comment: @David Where is PasteBin ? Likely the problem is From PNG Package Version, but i test above packages but don't work. I remember that my picture property form (form that add picture in design time) was different from standard form (Also My Memo forms), do JEDI package have PNG Encoding? and if i have multiple png package, how delphi decide use Which of them? do it decide with order of Library Path ?

Comment: @user Where is PasteBin? Do a websearch.